# How do I create separate zip files for each selected file/directory in 7zip?

Tags: zip, archiving, 7-zip, total-commander, packer

This is the internal zip packer from Total Commander:

[image: A picture of the Total Commander zip packer dialogue box.]

However I want to use my 7zip packer. When I select 5 files, I get 5 separate .zip archives for each selected file. How do I do that in 7zip?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I am not sure you can do what you are suggesting using the graphical user interface, but you can certainly from the command line:

```
FOR %i IN (*.*) DO 7z.exe a "%~ni.7z" "%i"
```

You would need to change directory (the `cd` command) to the `F:\Downloads` directory first, or whatever directory you would want to perform the mass compression. Also, it is easy enough to substitute in *.exe or whatever extension you want to filter for to just compress those documents.

And the secret decoder ring:

- `%i` is a variable that holds the file name for each step in the loop
- `(*.*)` is the selection criteria, it could easily be *.exe or similar
- `7z.exe` is the command line version of 7-Zip
- `%~ni` - this expands the %i variable to just the file name - no extension

If you wanted to just add the folders for a given directory, the command is a bit more complex as by default FOR just works with files. We need to feed it some additional information:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=?" %i IN (`DIR /B /A:D`) DO 7z.exe a "%i.7z" "%i"
```

This works because of a few pieces of what seems like magic:

- `/F` tells FOR to iterate over the expanded value in ()
- `usebackq` tells FOR that I am going to pass a command and use the output to iterate
- `delims=?` tells FOR that I want to break tokens apart on the `?` - an illegal character in file names and directories. I only want one token.
- The `/B` in `DIR` is for *bare format* - just the name
- The `/A:D` in `DIR` is for restricting the results by attribute, the D is for directories

If you want to encapsulate this inside of a batch file, the only change you will need to make is to double escape the %i variable:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.*) DO 7z.exe a "%%~ni.7z" "%%i"
```

Comment: Yea, except yours is 7z archive, I want a zip archive! So %~ni.zip instead?

Comment: Better yet, I want zip or 7z with ultra compression. AND pack it in d:\packed. But so far your method works!

Comment: Got it, thank you! FOR %i IN (*.*) DO 7z.exe a "i:\packed\%~ni.7z" "%i" -mx9

Comment: By the way, can you show me how to do that in a batch file? i.e. sperate-archive.bat

Comment: Thanks, and how do I add whole folders to that script, please?

Comment: I mean I've got 600+ folders and want them packed separately as 7z.

Comment: `(*.*)` actually is an impressed face by a user who has become confused of trying to understand your script code.

Answer (score 24):

I like Goyuix's answer.  However, if you are using Windows 7 (or have Power Shell installed) and also use the command-line version of 7-zip, 7za.exe, then you can run this command:

```
dir | ForEach-Object { & "7za.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name }
```

You can also change "dir" to "dir *.exe" to only select executable files.

One nice thing about Power Shell is that you are working with objects instead of strings.  So you could get really specific if you wanted to.  For example:

```
dir *.csv | ? { $_.Length -lt 18900 -and $_.LastWriteTime -ge [DateTime] "07/01/2011" } | ForEach-Object { & "7za.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name }
```

This will only include files that:

1. have a csv extension
2. less than 18,900 bytes in size
3. last modified on or after 7/1/2011

**EDIT**
If you want zip files instead of 7-zip files, use [InfoZip's zip.exe](http://www.info-zip.org/) instead.

Comment: 7-zip can also create zip files - have a look at the -t flag. Example: `7z a -tzip archive.zip *.exe`

Comment: Ok, $_.BaseName $_.Name works, but how do I do $_.BaseName $_.Name on another drive, in another directory? Say f:\test\file1.7z etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been working on exactly this problem and one of the issues I found was duplication of the folder name within the archive, i.e. when compressing a folder called "foo" an archive containing `.\foo\fighters.txt` is produced instead of just one containing `fighters.txt`.

The answer, therefore is to go into the directory being processed and have the archive appear in the previous (root) directory, then return to that directory in order to process the next folder.

It is also important to have 7ZIP ignore existing ZIP and CMD files within the root directory to prevent them ending up within the archive, hence the `-x!*.zip` and `-x!*.cmd` exclusion arguments.

This script will also maintain recursive folder structures.

```
@echo off

REM Ensures variables set within the batch file are local to
REM this script only and will be removed when finished.
setlocal

if exist *.zip goto zip_exist

for /d %%X in (*) do (
    cls
    cd /D %%X
    "e:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r  -x!*.zip -x!*.cmd "..\%%X.zip" "*.*"
    cd ..
)
goto end

:zip_exist
Echo.
Echo Note: for this script to work, compression of
Echo pre-existing zip files is not possible.

:end
pause
```

The above code should be copied to a batch file such as "compress_dirs.cmd" and run as admin from the directory containing the folders you wish to compress.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the folder structure, and save each file in its own structure, 
try this:

Save this command in a file with extension .bat and put it in the folder you need to zip:

```
FOR /R %%i IN (*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%i.7z" "%%i" -sdel
```

Note:

-sdel: Deletes the original file (optional, if you only want to keep the compressed file)

Comment: This is the good stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install 7zip plugin for Total Commander from http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm
Once you do that on the right side of the window from your screenshot there will be another selection for 7zip compression. With that option you can accomplish exactly what you are asking for.