# How would i make 7zip take a folder + subdirectories and individualy zip to bzip format each file in each sub directory

Tags: 7-zip

I want to know how to make 7zip take a folder + subdirectories and individualy zip to bzip format each file in each sub directory.

if there is not a way then oh well.

Comment: Do you have a preferred OS to do this in? It will help someone offer a suggestion as it will either be a small script or one-liner. It is more than possible =)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/311937/how-do-i-create-separate-zip-files-for-each-selected-file-directory-in-7zip