# How do I create seperate 7z files for each selected file/directory in 7zip?

Tags: zip, 7-zip, archiving, 7za

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I've looked around this site, I've googled, I've experimented. And, while I'm very, very close to where I want to go, there's one last hurdle I can't seem to get over. I would have posted a response to this thread...

[How do I create separate zip files for each selected file/directory in 7zip?](https://superuser.com/questions/311937/how-do-i-create-separate-zip-files-for-each-selected-file-directory-in-7zip)

..but I guess the passage of time has disallowed further comments to that post.

Anyway, here's what I want to accomplish in 7zip, from the command line:
-compress each individual file to its own archive
-maintain directory structure
-have the archives be in the same folders where their per-archived counterparts originated
-delete the original file after archiving

This command has got me so close...

`FOR /R %i IN (*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%i.7z" "%i" -sdel`

That command archives each individual file. It maintains the files in the directory structure. It deletes the original file after archiving. But, the naming is just a bit off. Example: I archive a file named "handsome.txt". Rather than leave me with the desired archive name of "handsome.7z", it leaving me with an archive called "handsome.txt.7z".

How in the world do I run this command, while having the archive names stop containing the original extension?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your command, when FOR /R scans the folder structure the parameter `"%i"` expands to each filename and extension but`"%~dpni"` will get just the path+filename without the extension. So try this to make the 7z file name as you want (you are just changing `"%i.7z"` to `"%~dpni.7z"`):

`FOR /R %i IN (*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%~dpni.7z" "%i" -sdel`

To see an explanation of how the tilde `~` character can modify variable substitution, including FOR metavariable expansion, type `FOR /?` at the prompt or see online references like these

[Parameter extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Or look for 'variable substitution' here:

[Windows Commands: FOR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)